# Grouping and Reordering data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some dataframe with a structure

```
Candidate   z0, 0deg    z0, 30deg   z0, 60deg   z0, 90deg   z0, 120deg  z0, 150deg  z0, 180deg  z0, 210deg  z0, 240deg  
10006A  0.30    0.05    0.05    0.05    0.05    0.30    0.05    0.05    0.05
10008A  0.30    0.30    0.30    0.30    0.30    0.30    0.30    0.05    0.05
```

What I would like to do is to restructure the dataframe so it looks like this

```
Candidate   angle   z0
10006A      0       0.30    
10006A      30      0.05    
10006A      60      0.05    
10006A      90      0.05    
10006A      120     0.05    
10006A      150     0.30    
10006A      180     0.05    
10006A      210     0.05    
10006A      240     0.05
10008A      0       0.30
...
```

I am completely blank on how to do this. The angle could be retrieved from the column name, but is ordered anyway from 0 to 330 in steps of 30 degree.

Can this be done in pandas?

Comment: Do you have other possibilities than `Candidate` and `z0, xxxdeg` as column names? (e.g. other `z1`, `z2`…)

Comment: The input date come in csv format and I can alter the column names. in the end there are only 36 of them , but ```z0``` is the value the first 12 should be aggregated under, the next 12 under ```c0``` and the last 12 under ```vb0```

Comment: OK, check if the answer below works for you and if not please update your example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with a bit of post-processing:

```
out = (pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['z0'], i='Candidate', j='angle',
                       sep=', ', suffix='\d+deg')
         .reset_index()
         .assign(angle=lambda d: d['angle'].str.removesuffix('deg').astype(int))
      )
```

Output:

```
   Candidate  angle    z0
0     10006A      0  0.30
1     10008A      0  0.30
2     10006A     30  0.05
3     10008A     30  0.30
4     10006A     60  0.05
5     10008A     60  0.30
6     10006A     90  0.05
7     10008A     90  0.30
8     10006A    120  0.05
9     10008A    120  0.30
10    10006A    150  0.30
11    10008A    150  0.30
12    10006A    180  0.05
13    10008A    180  0.30
14    10006A    210  0.05
15    10008A    210  0.05
16    10006A    240  0.05
17    10008A    240  0.05
```

With more `stubnames`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Candidate': ['10006A', '10008A'],
                   'z0, 0deg': [0.3, 0.3], 'z0, 30deg': [0.05, 0.3], 'z0, 60deg': [0.05, 0.3], 'z0, 90deg': [0.05, 0.3], 'z0, 120deg': [0.05, 0.3], 'z0, 150deg': [0.3, 0.3], 'z0, 180deg': [0.05, 0.3], 'z0, 210deg': [0.05, 0.05], 'z0, 240deg': [0.05, 0.05],
                   'c0, 0deg': [0.3, 0.3], 'c0, 30deg': [0.05, 0.3], 'c0, 60deg': [0.05, 0.3], 'c0, 90deg': [0.05, 0.3], 'c0, 120deg': [0.05, 0.3], 'c0, 150deg': [0.3, 0.3], 'c0, 180deg': [0.05, 0.3], 'c0, 210deg': [0.05, 0.05], 'c0, 240deg': [0.05, 0.05],
                   'vb0, 0deg': [0.3, 0.3], 'vb0, 30deg': [0.05, 0.3], 'vb0, 60deg': [0.05, 0.3], 'vb0, 90deg': [0.05, 0.3], 'vb0, 120deg': [0.05, 0.3], 'vb0, 150deg': [0.3, 0.3], 'vb0, 180deg': [0.05, 0.3], 'vb0, 210deg': [0.05, 0.05], 'vb0, 240deg': [0.05, 0.05],
                  })

out = (pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['z0', 'c0', 'vb0'], i='Candidate', j='angle', sep=', ', suffix='\d+deg').reset_index()
         .assign(angle=lambda d: d['angle'].str.removesuffix('deg').astype(int))
      )
```

Output:

```
   Candidate  angle    z0    c0   vb0
0     10006A      0  0.30  0.30  0.30
1     10008A      0  0.30  0.30  0.30
2     10006A     30  0.05  0.05  0.05
3     10008A     30  0.30  0.30  0.30
4     10006A     60  0.05  0.05  0.05
5     10008A     60  0.30  0.30  0.30
6     10006A     90  0.05  0.05  0.05
7     10008A     90  0.30  0.30  0.30
8     10006A    120  0.05  0.05  0.05
9     10008A    120  0.30  0.30  0.30
10    10006A    150  0.30  0.30  0.30
11    10008A    150  0.30  0.30  0.30
12    10006A    180  0.05  0.05  0.05
13    10008A    180  0.30  0.30  0.30
14    10006A    210  0.05  0.05  0.05
15    10008A    210  0.05  0.05  0.05
16    10006A    240  0.05  0.05  0.05
17    10008A    240  0.05  0.05  0.05
```

Comment: I went into the csv file and adjusted the column names, deleting all the 'deg' and '°' and ran the following:

```
test_df = pd.wide_to_long(in_df, stubnames=['z0','c0','vb0'], i='Candidate', j='angle', sep=', ').reset_index()
```
What is the purpose of the

```
.assign(angle=lambda d: d['angle'].str.removesuffix('deg').astype(int))
```

Comment: it is to remove the `deg`, convert to integer and assign back to the same name, you can remove it if you pre-processed the file ;)

Comment: When I use your second example I am getting an attribute error saying 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'removesuffix' but I am running Python 3.9.11 and removesuffix should be there.

Comment: Then try: `d['angle'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)`

Comment: to check your python version: `import sys ; print(sys.version)`